# Android Api 23 Change Navigation View headerLayout textview

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, header, textview, navigation-drawer

I am testing the Navigation Drawer sample project in android and i have a problem setting the text in navigation view profile header.

This is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    texto.setText("HELLO");
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom">

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing" android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" android:id="@+id/textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When i try to set the text of the textview i always get this error and it only happens with api level 23:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method   'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null   object reference
```

How can i change the Textview text of the nav_header_main.xml from the main activity??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having same issue. maybe a problem with library?

Comment: I have this problem too - introduced with the dependencies in com.android.support:* 23.1.0 . Reverting to 23.0.1 fixed it, so I'll stay with that until it's addressed.

Comment: Same problem here... I think its a bug in new `com.android.support:* 23.1.0`....

Comment: This indeed an issue with the design support library 23.1.0. Because the underlying implementation for the NavigationView is now a RecyclerView, the header layout is not inflated at runtime.  See link here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364276/getting-error-in-existing-code-after-updating-support-repository-to-23-1-0/33365230#33365230

Comment: On another note: this sort of thing makes me shudder for the future of the self-driving car!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to avoid it with this code:

```
    View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
    navigationView.addHeaderView(header);
    TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setText("HELLO");
```

Comment: Great answer. Works perfect

Comment: if this is the only solution, why do we have a xmls? isnt there a work around to change via xml itself?

Comment: This works fine, remove `
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"` to avoid duplicate headers.

Comment: At `LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);`, AndroidStudio complains with `Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element)`. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I still get the same crash when I deploy a debug apk, however, every app launch thereafter works properly...

Comment: @orium Thanks a lot for the great solution .. Also, View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); helped me..

Answer (score 58):

Now with the 23.1.1 release of the design support library, you can use

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: You can also use `navigationView.getHeaderCount()` in case you have more than 1 header for whatever reason.

Comment: This is the right answer as of 23.1.1 of the support library.

Comment: Worked for me : support-v4:24.1.1

Answer (score 7):

Orium answer works and this will work as well.

```
View header = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
    TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    texto.setText("HELLO");
```

Answer (score 1):

this solved the problem for me

```
    View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.header_view);

    txt_fullname = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullname);
    txt_email = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View headerView=navigationView.getChildAt(0);
TextView tvName=(TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.name);
TextView tvEmail=(TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.email);

    tvName.setText(data);
    tvEmail.setText(data);
```

Comment: This solution works.
I also tried:
`textView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textview);`
and
`View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_header, null);
navigationView.addHeaderView(header);
textView = header.findViewById(R.id.textview);`
but unfortunately without success. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you use this attribute:

```
<android.support.desibn.widget.NavigationView>
    ...
    app:headerLayout="@layout/your_header_layout"/>
```

You can:

```
View header = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView title = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.your_title_id);
//Or something else
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is right but in kotlin, you need to use `findViewById<View>`

```
   val navigationHeader = navigation_view.getHeaderView(0)
        val navigationTitle = navigationHeader.findViewById<View>(R.id.txt_navigation_title) as TextView
        navigationTitle.text = "This is your header"
```