# TextView in Header layout in NavigationView

Tags: android

I am using following code to get `TextView` from `Navigationview`'s `headerLayout`.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

txtName = (TextView) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
txtName.setText("Guna");
```

This code works if I use following dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

But it throws `NullPointerException` at `txtName.setText("Guna");` if I change the dependency to

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

I don't know how to resolve this.

Exception Log from LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: can you post your log?

Comment: It's an known bug [Check this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190786&q=-has%3Arestrict&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199764/android-api-23-change-navigation-view-headerlayout-textview

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thank you bro... I don't know how could I missed it :(

Comment: @Gunaseelan No problem .Just move ahead