# How to fix this error AAPT2 error: check logs for details?

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, build.gradle

I have a problem with my android studio. When I want to create a project or I want to open my previous project get this error `AAPT2 error: check logs for details` 
and when I check logs take this error

```
error: attribute 'com.example.mahdi.servicemanager:headerLayout' not found.
```

My project was already working properly but now take error and I don't understand why take error:
XML code:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

The build.gradle is **below:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mahdi.servicemanager"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: add your `nav_header_main` layout file and `app/gradle.build` in the question too

Comment: I added my build gradle code:

Comment: change to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199764/android-api-23-change-navigation-view-headerlayout-textview

Comment: Dear friend, my navigation don't have any error, when I want to create project or open my previous project get error, I think my gradle has error please check my gradle code

Answer (score 0):

try adding this `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your layout